# GWT file upload

Tags: java, gwt, file-upload

I have a following problem - we are using `FormPanel` which sends file to the Servlet which takes the arguments and tries to parse `XML` from this file. This works fine.

Problem is when the user uploaded a wrong file, so parsing ends with `SAXException` which I would like to propagate (or the exception's message) to client. I tried something like

```
catch (SAXException ex) {
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE);
    response.flushBuffer();
}
```

but it's not working, I always get empty tag pre (`<pre></pre>`). I am trying to catch this with

```
formPanel.addSubmitCompleteHandler(new SubmitCompleteHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onSubmitComplete(SubmitCompleteEvent event) {
        String s = event.getResults();
    });
```

I can use `response.getWriter().write("Error");` in my Servlet but how the client will know if the error really occured or not?Using something like `event.getResults().contains("error")` doesn't seem to me as a correct solution.

So I am thinking about using `RequestBuilder` but I don't see a way how could I get the the uploaded file and push it to my servlet. Or maybe converting my message to `JSON` would help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should refer to [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-web-toolkit/EjhCnRLJv_g/AlI810MsnNUJ) on the google gwt discussion group. The way you described, parsing the `event.getResults()` to determine if there was an error or the result in case of a success is the correct way to do it, even though it might seem barbaric.

As suggested in the linked discussion, you can look into [GWT Upload](http://code.google.com/p/gwtupload/) for cleaner code, as well as upload progress information. I believe your only two options to upload files to a server from a web page are forms or Flash.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I will look at GWT Upload library.